# React Start Kit unexpected token export function format(time OSX)

Tags: reactjs, macos, webpack, babeljs, yarnpkg

I'm trying to use:
https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

it works on my windows machine, but on OSX I'm getting the following:

/data/dev/zmern/react-starter-kit/tools/run.js:10
export function format(time) {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

what could the issue be in osx?